# How can I restore Postgres backup extension file in windows?

Tags: postgresql

Let's start with basic info: 
-OS Windows Server 2012R2
-Postgres 9.5

I'm trying to restore a .backup file from a backup generated from the pgadmin3 interface.

I've tried restoring it using the GUI and psql and pg_restore. 
I always receive the following error :

> [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive

Here's a sample of my pg_restore command

> D:>pg_restore  -d newDB -h HOSTNAME  -U someuser -v -F c
>   "D:\BackupFull.backup"  pg_restore: [archiver] did
>   not find magic string in file header

or

> D:>pg_restore  -d newDB -h HOSTNAME -U someuser 
>   "D:\BackupFull.backup"
>   pg_restore: [archiver] input
>   file does not appear to be a valid archive

Am I doing something wrong or is my file corrupted somehow.

Thanks,

Comment: It seems you created the backup as a plain text (SQL) dump, you need to use `psql` to run the SQL script

Comment: Just got news back from IT , they told me they used pg_dump with -Z 9   parameter.   I tried unzipping the file with 7zip to no avail